# Can't get OV2640 Camera initilized on ESP32 DevKitC Rover running Zephyr

Tags: esp32, zephyr-rtos

I'm trying to get the OV2640 Camera working with Zephyr on ESP32. There exists a driver for this module in Zephyr and is configured in prj.conf using CONFIG_I2C=y, CONFIG_VIDEO=y, CONFIG_VIDEO_OV2640=y. My overlay file is as such:

```
&i2c0 {
    status = "okay";
    clock-frequency = <I2C_BITRATE_STANDARD>;
    sda-gpios = <&gpio0 26 (GPIO_PULL_UP | GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;
    scl-gpios=  <&gpio0 27 (GPIO_PULL_UP | GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;
    ov2640: ov2640@60 {
        compatible = "ovti,ov2640";
        reg = <0x60>; 
        label = "ov2640";
    };
};
```

The generated device tree looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qjMN.png)
Using the sample/basic/minimal the camera is not listed as an i2c device.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qocAA.png)
I'm not sure what could be the cause of this. Possibly the device not being powered?

The setup is pretty straight forward from what I can tell. I expected it to be listed as a device.